# Angular date Filter for

Tags: angularjs

I'm calculating a time duration in milliseconds with moment JS. In my view i want it to show up in the style of "25:25" for a duration of 25 Hours and 25 Minutes.

I've already tried the angular date filter like this:

```
<h3>My Duration: {{ controller.myDurationInMillisecs | date:'HH:mm' }}</h3>
```

But then, as soon as the duration is larger than 23:59, it starts counting from 00:00. Guess I have to use an other Angular Filter but I do't know which one.

Note: It's not possible to use MomentJS .format() funtion here for me. 
Can someone help?

My Controller Code looks like:

```
vm.overallDuration = 0;

vm.items = [
    {"duration":"00:00"},
    {"duration":"01:00"},
    {"duration":"25:00"}
]
vm.calculateOverallDuration = function () {
    angular.forEach(vm.items, function (item) {
        if (item.duration) {
            var timeFlownTillNow = $moment.duration(vm.overallDuration);
            var duration = $moment.duration(item.duration);
            vm.statistics.all.time = timeFlownTillNow.add(duration)._milliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why It's not possible to use MomentJS .format() there?

Comment: Wrap moment in a service, inject the service into your controller and call the service method like so: `$scope.format = function(value) { return momentService.format(value); }`

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the [angular-duration-filter](https://github.com/erykpiast/angular-duration-format). It does exactly what i want :) Whis that angular supports something like this natively..